# Adding padding following custom home icon in mobile menu (Blogger)

Tags: mobile, menu, blogger

Mobile Menu

[image: xxx]

Hi- I was hoping to get some help on how to add spacing underneath my custom home icon and my name in my Blogger mobile menu (I attached a pic). I apologize but this is a custom Blogger template but the author doesn't have any time to help me.

Thank you so much!       [www.thenorthernmagnolia.com](http://www.thenorthernmagnolia.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS code to your template

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .menu-home-icon img {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!